# C++ preprocessor and operator + overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, c-preprocessor

I want to use the C++ preprocessor to be able to write the following in any C++ block.

```
class Student {
private:
    int age;
    int grade;
    int courses;

}

int main(){
    CREATE_STUDENT 15+62+2 ;
}
```

The previous code will create a Student with these 3 members.
I want to use `+` operator overloading.

Any idea of how to do it?
I want EXACTLY the syntax I mentioned above.

Comment: Why would you want to do that rather than a plain object creation? (Note that the preprocessor has finished running way before operator overloading is even considered.)

Comment: Why not a constructor: `Student(int a_age, int a_grade, int a_courses) : age(a_age), grade(a_grade), courses(a_courses) {}` ? Use it like `Student s(15, 62, 2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I completely fail to understand *why* you would want to do such a thing. But it is possible, sorta.

You'll need to make it a bit more complex than that to be able to use more than one such "construct" in the same block though.

```
#include <iostream>

#define GRADE_STUDENT Student student = (Student)

class Student {
    public:
        Student(int a): age(a), grade(-1), courses(-1), setup(0) {};
        Student& operator+(int p)
        {
            switch(setup) {
                case 0: grade = p; break;
                case 1: courses = p; break;
                default: /* die */ char *p=0; *p=0;
            }
            setup++;
            return *this;
        };
        void print()
        {
            std::cout << age << ", " << grade << ", " << courses << std::endl;
        };
    private:
        int age;
        int grade;
        int courses;
        int setup;
};

int main()
{
    {
        GRADE_STUDENT 15+62+2 ;
        student.print();
    }
    {
        GRADE_STUDENT 15+62 ;
        student.print();
    }
    {
        GRADE_STUDENT 15+62+2+3 ; // crash
    }
    return 42;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this response. This is the way i tried to approach it, but this codeGRADE_STUDENT 15+62+2 ; adds the expression 15, 62 and 2 before the function call Student& operator+(int p).

Comment: Thank you very much. I was trying this but without the casting to Student. Indeed using this casting, enters constructor before the add expression.

Comment: Now could you _please_ explain _why_ you want this? It is a really, really bad idea.

Comment: A cleaner way is to use the type system to detect wrong number of operands at compile-time: http://ideone.com/H6Gc7.

Comment: @visitor: you could post that as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use a constructor:

```
class Student {
private:
    int age;
    int grade;
    int courses;
public:
    Student(int a, int g, int c)
    {
        age = a;
        grade = g;
        courses = c;
    }
}

int main(){
    Student s(15,62,2);
}
```

Comment: i want to do it using C++ preprocessor. I want exactly the syntax i wrote in main.

Comment: I'm not even sure if it's possible to do what you're suggesting, but even if you could, why would you want to?! The code I provided is congruent with standard C++ whereas your suggestion is dangerous, not at all standard C++ and is difficult to understand from a logical stand point.

Comment: "What's the problem, sir?" -- "I'm afraid your language doesn't fit my syntax." ... That's a very odd request, and I doubt you can hope that there's a general solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should template your class instead of working with the preprocessor.